# Javascript code to get several random elements from array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've just started with JS, and I'm trying to get random elements from an array. The amount is decided by a user's input, and that part works, I think. The functions are called by onClick of buttons.
Scouring the internet has given me the solution below as the best one, but I can't make the part of fetching elements work even in console.log.

What I actually see in console is an empty array [] with length:0

What's the matter with my code? This is the way to do it I keep seeing on forums and people say it works for them and it's basically the same code with changed words.

```
userArray = [];

    function addElement(){
        let element = document.getElementById("add-input").value;
        userArray.push(element); 
        document.getElementById("add-input").value = "";
    }


    function getElements(){
        let amount = document.getElementById("amount-input").value;
        newList = []; 
        for(i=0; i<amount.value; i++){
        randomElement = userArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * userArray.length)];
        newList.push(randomElement);
        }
        console.log(newList);
    }
```

```
   <div class="phase-add">
        <p class="label-p">Input an element</p>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input class="add-input" type="text" name="add-input" id="add-input">
            <button class="add-btn" onclick="addElement()">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="phase-get">
        <div class="input-box">
            <p class="label-p">Choose the amount</p>
            <input type="text" name="amount-input" id="amount-input">
        </div>
        <button onclick="getElements()">Get elements</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you include the HTML that goes with it so that we can run your code? And even better; look for the `<>` icon in your question editor to make a snippet which makes your code runnable on this page.

Comment: One problem is that an <input>'s value is always a string. So depending on how you use it, you will have to turn it into a number first. Here for instance you can use `i < +amount.value`

Comment: Also you're appending .value twice. `amount` is already the value, as string. Fixed example code: https://jsfiddle.net/2a6pq9je/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Variable `amount` is already a string/number. You need not get the value of it again in the for loop. Changing to `for(i=0; i<amount; i++){` in for loop will fix the issue.

```js
userArray = [];

function addElement(){
    let element = document.getElementById("add-input").value;
    userArray.push(element); 
    document.getElementById("add-input").value = "";
}


function getElements(){
    let amount = document.getElementById("amount-input").value;
    console.log(amount)
    newList = []; 
    for(i=0; i<amount; i++){
      randomElement = userArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * userArray.length)];
      newList.push(randomElement);
    }
    console.log(newList);
}
```

```html
<input id = "add-input" type = "text" ></input>
<button onclick = "addElement()">Add Element</button>
<input id = "amount-input" type = "number"></input>
<button onclick = "getElements()">Get Elements</button>
```